# Google calendar watch for updates on events

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, zapier

I want to listen programmatically when an event I created on the Google calendar is updated (like when someone accept/reject an invite) and I want to receive the relevant info regarding the event (type, confirmed/declined attendees, etc). I've tried using zapier and so far it does the job. Is there a native way to do that using Google API? I've also tried using Google calendar push notifications but the data I've received from the webhook isn't sufficient for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details why: when using "push notifications the data received from the webhook isn't sufficient"? Maybe you can add: "This is what/how I tried" (code), and "This is the data I need"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a small [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

Their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) explains the process of listening for a calendar change event. Then, you'll need to [perform an incremental sync](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync) with the Calendar Sync API and handle the specifics of the event based on how you want.

Note that more simply, a [webhook](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) may suffice for your use case.